# Knockout.js progress bar width from json number

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a number pulled in from json. Using knockout.js I want to read that number and use it to set the width of a div. eg: a number of 50 would equal 50px width on div.

How can I create a function in knockout.js to do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/zEWuZ/

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="days-due" data-bind="text: daysDue"></span> days due
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </li>
</ul>

// Here's my data model
var viewModel;
$.getJSON('http://echo.jsontest.com/daysDue/50', function (data) {
    viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

edit: this works in my fiddle now but something is wrong here. Is it something to do with my data.dueDays?

```
    // Here's my data model
    var viewModel;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('my/json', function (data) { 
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data.workflowItemViewModels, {}, viewModel.workflowItemViewModels);

            viewModel = new DashboardViewModel();

            viewModel.barWidth = "width: " + data.dueDays + "px";

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

here's one possible way as an example:

```
// Here's my data model
var viewModel;
   $.getJSON('http://echo.jsontest.com/daysDue/50', function (data) {
    viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);   
    viewModel.barWidth = "width: " + data.daysDue + "px;";
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

and bind as

```
 <div class="bar" data-bind="attr: { style: barWidth }"></div>
```

Comment: works in my fiddle but in my actual code something is wrong. Is it something to do with data.dueDays?

Comment: you mean data.daysDue? What's happening in your code, what's the error?

Comment: i changed it to dueDays for my real code. "view model is undefinded."

Comment: My issue is getting away from this. It is dealing with a forEach that makes my error related to that level and not the same as this example. I will have to approach it from a different direction than this. Thanks for the help though.